# Is there some way I can control the user location in Flutter through buttons on the screen?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-android-api-2

For a school project, my group decided to develop a mobile application involving a map in Flutter. However, I have an iPhone, so it is easier for me to write and test my code on my computer. However, because I am on my computer, I can't easily walk around and test location related functionality. Is there some way I can use buttons or code to control the blue dot which represents the user's location?

I have managed to control the camera position programmatically, and it looks like most functionality comes form properties of the GoogleMap element, but there does not seem to be a user location property that I can modify. I also did some Google searching and found results that claimed to move the user location, but actually just moved the camera. I am using Android Studio and an emulated Android to run and test my code, and am using the Google Maps package for mapping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as you start using this platform. And regarding your question, if you're using Android Studio, you can actually change the emulator's current location. Please also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.